# Change azure plan location

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I am new in Azure, I need to create a Web Apllication.

So I created an WebApplication (ASP.NET Core), when Published it via Visual Studio it created me an "Azure Plan" in "SouthCentral US" (I had no choice in the VS Publish Interface), but I need it in "Western Europe".

So can I change the location now in AZure portal, or maybe delete the Plan and recreate the new one in the correct location ? What would be the cost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can only move Web Apps to new app service plans in the same region. So in your example you would need to create a new App Service plan in the correct region and redeploy your application to that. You can create App service plans through the portal. I use Visual Studio community and when I deploy web apps through it I get the choice of which App Service plan to deploy it to.

Comment: This is correct. If you have done any heavy customisation of things like app settings etc. you could use the deployment script option to download an ARM template of what you created and use that to re-deploy, but if it's fairly generic I would create new.

Comment: unfortunately when in VS you do "create new" the interface proposes you just the group /plan name, any way of select a location for that plan, so it make it in Southern US... (

Comment: So, I had no premium account, I couldn't clone the application, so needed to remove my application, remove the group, remove the plan, recreate the plan on the azure portal in the right location, then the group and finally the web app... very inconvenient